# How can I send a variable to a form using this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, variables, forms, onclick, submit

I've got this onclick call:

```
onClick="mySubmit();
```

which calls this function:

```
function mySubmit(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

which then submits this form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="action.php" method="post">
```

**My question is:** how do I send a variable to the form from the onClick to get something like `<form id="myForm" action="action.php?id=**(the variable sent from the onclick goes here)**" method="post">`

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easiest way: append a hidden field to the form.

```
<form id="myForm" action="action.php" method="post">
  <input type='hidden' id= 'hiddenField' name='id' value='' />

<script> 
  function mySubmit() {
     document.getElementById('hiddenField').value = "Whatever I want here";
     document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
   }
</script>
```

Or use a function like

```js
function addHiddenField(form, props) {
  Object.keys(props).forEach(fieldName => {
    var field = form[fieldName];
    if (!field) {
      field = document.createElement('input');
      field.type = 'hidden';
      field.name = fieldName;
      form.appendChild(field);
    }
    field.value = props[fieldName];
  });
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
  addHiddenField(this, {
    someQueryName: 'someQueryValue',
    otherQueryName: 'otherVal'
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  Name
  <input name=name />
  <input type=submit />
</form>
```

Note that you can use DevTools to modify the iframe's sandbox to allow it to submit forms and you can verify the posted URL. `sandbox="... allow-forms"`

Answer (score 6):

place a input type hidden inside the form then submit the form

```
<input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" />
```

set the value of the hidden field in your javascript submit()

```
document.getElementById('id').value = **;
```

but by setting form method="post" the id will not be the part of query string, i.e. the url will remain action.php
instead
if you really want the id in query string i.e. url action.php?id=** then you need to change the form method="get", by this the hidden field id will automatically be the part of the url i.e action.php?id=**

read about [difference between get and post](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)

[here is how you access posted value on next page](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp) if you really need to use method="post" action="action.php"

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML :

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
            <input type='hidden' id="id" name='id' value='123' />
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Click me !' onclick='addParam()' />
        </form>
```

Your Script :

```
function addParam() {

                var url = "action.php?id=" + document.getElementById('id').value;
                document.getElementById("myForm").setAttribute('action', url);

            }
```

Thank You.